# kill long running MySQL process on window close event from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache

We have a long running SQL in a PHP process. Sometimes, user close the window and the SQL still keeps running in background , killing the performance of server.

Can SQL be stopped as soon as PHP process is killed on closing the window?

I think I will need to handle window close event in browser and do some exception handling in php script on occurrence of the event ..

Comment: You appear to execute the whole sql script as one block from php , if this is the case then try to break your scripts into chuncks in php code because as php sends script to database server then it is the task of db server to execute !! :)

Comment: What MySQL client library are you using?  The default behavior on every one that I have used is to **not** use persistent connections, meaning what you ask should already be happening unless you are doing something strange.

Comment: @Muhannad, Your comment makes no sense, and is inaccurate.

Comment: @Brad Prove your claim! :)

Comment: @Muhannad, "You appear to execute the whole sql script as one block from php"  It doesn't matter.  Multiple statements or not, the database server will execute them in order, just as it would if you sent them one at a time.  I'll leave proving this up to you.  ":)"

Comment: @brad you misunderstand  , What I mean when you send the whole script to mysql server it executes it and php still waitinf for the result but when you divid the scripts in php for exampe first exectures select then insert then update one by one php statements then you will have contol over execution of scripts!!!

Comment: @Muhannad, I think I see what you are getting at.  There aren't many situations where that applies, but yes, I apologize that is something you can do.  Just be very careful though when inserting data based on a select.  That should be done in one statement so you don't run into issues with concurrent inserts.

Comment: @Brad I see your concern but my comment was for this specific issue , if we can break the query into smaller queries it will be safer in this case , because it appears that the query is huge and take too much time to complete

Comment: I would be asking why the query is taking so long in the first place. Are the joins correct? Are there indices on the necessary columns etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 independant 'process' here, browser, php and sql.

Php won't know it the browser has been closed and therefore can't kill the sql process. If the query is taking so long then the php will timeout anyway. This is usually set to 30 seconds.